# Trying to push a new projekt to Heroku, but it pushes an old project instead

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-cli

I'm currently working with Git and Heroku.

I committed changes to a project that I would like to upload to Heroku. I've been having some trouble beforehand so I had 5 projects earlier that I had to delete. Now when I use "heroku create", it creates a new project, but then why I use "git push heroku master", it tries to push an old project, which obviously fails because the project was deleted. Any tips on this? [screenshot of my cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L4Xi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to change Heroku's remote URL. Check [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps) article.

Comment: Thanks, I think that did it